# can I animate colors on materials the way falloffs are animated?

Tags: materials, animation-nodes

I'm thinking of a large matrix of splines that should have a delayed animation on their color.

Comment: Please be more specific, show some examples and what you have by now.

Comment: While you can animate colours, do you want each item animated at a different time, then each will need it's own material. Do you want the whole object changing at once or from the top of the object to  the bottom? You may want to look at [dynamic paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/dynamic_paint/introduction.html) for a way to control colour change.

Answer (score 1):

Press "I" while your mouse is over the color in your material settings. It will add a keyframe. Then go into the Graph Editor to edit the curve:
[image]